# Why doesn't Javascript recognize the HTML class attribute?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with a Javascript question, please? Why does the following code display only message boxes with the word "null" in them? And I think there are not enough of them either.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showElementClasses(node)  {
            var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
                alert(els[i].getAttribute("class"));
                alert("Class: " + els[i].className);
        }

        showElementClasses(document);
    </script>
</head>
<body class="bla">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 500; height: 400" id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is * a valid wildcard character? Also, your for loop needs more braces.

Comment: The * is correct (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-getElementsByTagName), the braces aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showElementClasses(node)  
        {

            alert("hello, world.");        
            var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
            {
                alert(els[i].getAttribute("class"));
                alert("Class: " + els[i].className);
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body class="bla" onload="showElementClasses(document)">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 500; height: 400" id="map" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Why does it only work if the call is put into the onload attribute? Is the <script> executed before the <body> is even created?

Comment: Putting the call in the onload for the body tag insures that all of the tags in the entire document are loaded before you try to 'getElementsByTagName' for that document (unless you have elements AFTER the body tag ends, which isn't likely) since the body tag is the last tag in the document. Yes, you're correct, the script call is executed as soon as the line is parsed inside the script call so it's going to cause some problems for that method.

Answer (score 2):

Also you forgot braces after `for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)` and `alert("Class: " + els[i].className);`.

Comment: Seems like I've been working with Python too much lately :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that your `alert("Class: " + els[i].className);` statement is not being run inside your `for` loop. You need to correct your braces.